# Kotlin: the most effective way to find first index of minimum element in some list of some objects

Tags: kotlin

I have some list of instances of some custom class:

```
data class Flight(val duration: Int)
```

For example:

```
val flights = listOf(Flight(10), Flight(5), Flight(5), Flight(15), Flight(20))
```

How to most effectively find first index of the minimum element in this list? In that case the first index of min element is 1, because flights[1].duration = 5.

Comment: do you really need the index value? wouldn't the object itself already suffice?

Comment: Here's a concise expression: `flights.withIndex().minBy { (_, f) -> f.duration }?.index`. But I think it will allocate O(n) temporary objects.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why didn't you post that as an answer? This is the best approach!

Comment: @WilliMentzel It's concise but I don't think it's the best at efficiency. The approach in one of the answers, with two scans and `equals` matching to find the item, might even beat it in performance because it doesn't create GC pressure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this would be "most efficient", I guess:

```
var min: Pair<Int, Flight>? = null
for (f in flights.withIndex()) {
    if (min == null || min.second.duration > f.value.duration) min = f.index to f.value
}
```

And this one does basically the same and looks much better:

```
flights.withIndex().minBy { (_, f) -> f.duration }?.index
```

Comment: I think this is the recommended approach – and more "kotlin-y" – because of its time efficiency, as `withIndex()` returns a lazy iterable

Comment: Whether lazy or not, it has the potential to create GC pressure. To get around it, one would need to do "manual" indexed iteration and manual bookkeeping to find the minimum. So it would be much more code.

Comment: I think your answer is the best, thank you! @MarkoTopolnik thanks for your comments, can you explain please why second approach has potential to create GC pressure? You think that first approach is more effective than second, right?

Comment: Both approaches are the same in this respect. As soon as you use `withIndex()`, you get a sequence of newly-created instances that hold both the item and its index. Check [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260387/1103872)'s second solution to see what I meant with "much more code" to get a zero-garbage solution. If I'm not allowed to assume anything about the size of the input, that's the solution i'd go with. But as soon as I can assume a small number of items and the code not being involved in a hot loop, I'd go with the more compact variants.

Comment: I disagree with lazy iterables being more efficient as an absolute truth.
Lazy iterables are more efficient only when there's a chance they won't be used (or used partially). But if you know the whole sequence is going to be used right away, laziness offers no advantage whatsoever. If anything it just adds more objects for the GC to collect. That said, I would expect the overhead to be minimal.

Answer (score 6):

With [minBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) to get the list item with the minimum duration 
and then [indexOf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of.html) to get its index:

```
val index = flights.indexOf(flights.minBy { it.duration })
```

For just 1 scan of the list, you can do a classic loop:

```
var index = if (flights.isEmpty()) -1 else 0
flights.forEachIndexed { i, flight ->
    if (flight.duration < flights[index].duration) index = i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val index = flights.minBy { it.duration }?.let { flights.indexOf(it) }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Kotlin 1.6 at least, `minBy` is deprecated.  Use `minByOrNull`:

```
data class Flight(val duration: Int)
val flights = listOf(Flight(10), Flight(5), Flight(5), Flight(15), Flight(20))
val minIndex = flights.withIndex().minByOrNull { (_, f) -> f.duration }?.index ?: throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
println(minIndex)
```